# how can I read the logging for odoo enterprise 14 installed on ubuntu 20

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm developing a custom module for odoo and suddenly got this error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

And I don't know how to find the problem
I'm using odoo enterprise 14 installed on ubuntu 20
Please I need a way to understand what happen

Comment: There are a lot possibilities how to install odoo. So you should add some more information to your question. But usually the logs are in `/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log`

Comment: I tried to find the odoo-server.log but its not there
I have downloaded the installable (Ubuntu • Debian) enterprise version from odoo download page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the status of the odoo service and will tell you the output of the logfile.

Try

```
sudo service odoo status
```

or

```
sudo service odoo-server status
```

The output will show the location of the log file.

Comment: Yes, I got this
root@ubuntu:/home/***# sudo service odoo status
● odoo.service - Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-06-04 21:23:01 +03; 2h 11min ago
   Main PID: 8871 (odoo)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 4614)
     Memory: 84.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/odoo.service
             └─8871 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/odoo --config /etc/odoo/odoo.conf --l>

Then I found the log location after going to lib/systemd/system/odoo.service

Thank you